# Can one setup dev/random when using a VM(virtual machine)?

Tags: unix, random, operating-system, vmware

Does anyone know if it's possible to setup dev/random when running the OS within a VM (VMWare in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "setup"? /dev/random will be available in the VM, and work just fine.

Comment: I was using OpenSolaris in a VM (on windows) and it complained it couldn't find dev/random. However I upgraded OpenSolaris to a dev build and it seems to work. Not really sure where the problem was and how it got solved but it was.

Comment: Anyways +1 for answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Tis is not an answer but a workaround: When I had the same problem I generated the keys on a physical machine and copied it.

Comment: Yeah that's a good band-aid until one can clear out the specifics