# Random Binary Generator (not pseudo)

Tags: c#, c++

How do I generate random binary values lets say 10 digits `0010101001` and I want to call this `C1` I then want to create another one called `C2` same again random 10 digit binary number.

C# is my language of choice.

Is there a bitset class for c#

something simple would be nice, like

```
int C1

for ( int C1 = 0; <=10; C1++)
     output bitset<0>

return 0;
```

Need to store c1 and c2 tho.

Comment: If you want it so it isn't pseudo random, you need an outside source of data that isn't pseudo random. Good luck. Physics has yet to prove that one exists.

Comment: What's wrong with a pseudo RNG?

Comment: To generate truly random values, you need a source of randomness. Which means you have to go outside of your PC. Some people have used radioactive decay (http://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/), some look at cosmic background radiation, some use a lava lamp. Do you really want true randomness?

Comment: Why is a pseudo-random source insufficient?  If you can answer that question, then you might get better answers.

Comment: @Garrith: How would you define (or detect) the difference between 'real' and 'pseudo' random numbers>

Comment: Look at my answer [here][1]. Has links to libraries that do what you need.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-to-generate-random-int-number-c/22697508#22697508

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function randomInt(max)
    // produces integer with uniform distribution between [0,max)
    # this should be in your standard library
    # though perhaps not by this name; and you may need to
    # initialize and maybe randomly seed your RNG beforehand

myRandomBinaryNumber = randomInt(2^10)  // then cast it if required
```

edit: this answer added before "(not pseudo)" added to title

edit: I recommend the methods listed in other answers, depending on one's needs (pseudorandom, cryptographically pseudorandom, truly random, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

If you want true random numbers, you need hardware your computer probably doesn't have. However, it can be added simply and cheaply - see [here](http://www.entropykey.co.uk),for example.

However, I think that a good pseudo-random generator, such as those that come with Boost - see [Boost random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254909/boost-random-number-generator) for an example, will be sufficient for  your needs

Comment: On Linux, I believe that entropy can also be gathered from noise and temperature readings and such and used to generate "truly" random numbers (at a slow rate) via /dev/random. However, this is more difficult for virtual machines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265591/can-one-setup-dev-random-when-using-a-vmvirtual-machine This is a sidenote, as this person is working with C#.

Comment: @ninja Unfortunately, you can quickly run out of entropy (and I thought it was supposed to be increasing!) using /dev/random, which is where devices like the USB stick I supplied  a link to come in.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the [rdrand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) instruction available in Ivy Bridge Intel processors. It's entropy source uses thermal noise within the silicon (See [DRNG Software Implementation Guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-digital-random-number-generator-drng-software-implementation-guide)).

Intel provides [rdrand C++ library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/user-manual-for-the-rdrand-library-windows-version). So you'll need to write managed C++ wrapper assembly to use it from C#. I've just compiled test project using the library, but my processor doesn't support the instruction.

Comment: There's a C# implementation that uses the rdrand instruction at https://github.com/JebteK/RdRand/tree/master/Versions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for either the `BitArray` class or the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class.

Answer (score 1):

Googling for [C# random number] results in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvcs/thread/55fb3116-c978-4ac8-9381-a2605e16e256 as the third hit.

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 2^10);
```

That being said, you are probably looking for a "pseudorandom" source.

edit: this answer added before "(not pseudo)" added to title